# parentElement and commonParentElement for getting parent element

Tags: javascript

parentElement( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534327(VS.85).aspx ) and commonParentElement( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa704196(VS.85).aspx ) are two methods in javascript.

When should I use these methods for getting the parent element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the parent node in javascript, you always want to do:

```
node.parentNode
```

You can readup on it [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/parentNode).

Comment: instead of node, if I have range, probably I can not use node.parentNode

Comment: @Hoque: Are you getting confused with `TextRange` objects, which have a `parentElement()` method?

Comment: Yes, I am confused with the above two methods used in TextRange.